# building R packages to use ASAN

Tags: r, rcpp, address-sanitizer

**Background**: I am developing a package that uses Rcpp and contains some C++ files. I would like to analyze my code with ASAN. I am struggling to build my package.

**What I have done so far**

1. I am using `https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/r-devel-san` docker container that comes with pre-built R (or RD) for working with ASAN.
2. Within this container, I could run a C++ script with `-fsanitize=address` flag to get a meaningful ASAN output.
3. My `src/Makevars` files look like the following (not all flags are relevant to this question):

```
CC = gcc -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer
CXX = g++
LDFLAGS = -fsanitize=address
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-sanitize-address-use-after-scope -D_GCL_RHACK_ -DGC_NO_MUTEX -m64 -ldl -lpthread -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wno-unused -DNDEBUG -g -std=c++17
PKG_CFLAGS = -fsanitize=address -D_GCL_RHACK_ -fno-sanitize-address-use-after-scope
```

4. To install, I do (from the directory containing my package directory `foo`):

```
RD CMD build foo
RD CMD install -l temp_lib/ foo_1.0.tar.gz
```

The install command throws the following error (along with the last line of teh build)

```
-g -O2  -c loadpathutil.c -o loadpathutil.o
g++ -fsanitize=undefined,bounds-strict -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++17 -shared -L/usr/local/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o foo.so RcppExports.o Read.o Utilities.o Write.o gdxcc.o loadpathutil.o -L/usr/local/lib/R/lib -lR
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘foo’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
installing to /work/temp_lib/00LOCK-foo/00new/foo/libs

unable to load shared object '/work/temp_lib/00LOCK-foo/00new/foo/libs/foo.so':
  /work/temp_lib/00LOCK-foo/00new/foo/libs/foo.so: undefined symbol: __asan_option_detect_stack_use_after_return
```

I understand that the final package shared object has to be somehow linked to ASAN but the suggested solutions `LDFLAGS`, `PKG_LDFLAGS` don't seem to help.

Comment: I wrote that container, but even I now often switch to Winston's `wch1/r-debug` container (see https://github.com/wch/r-debug) and I just debugged a SAN issue with it last week.  If you just invokes the correct `RD*` and `RDscript*` frontend everything should work.  First step is always to reproduce a known issue -- and my `sanitizers` package at https://cran.r-project.org/package=sanitizers can help with that.

Comment: Thanks Dirk.  That was indeed the missing piece. Worked like magic.

Answer (score 0):

This the document I wrote for myself and that I used myself.

1. Download and decrompress [R source code](https://cran.r-project.org/sources.html)
2. Install the compiler `clang`. `apt-get install clang` should do the job
3. Open `config.site` and add the following at the end

```bash
## clang-ASAN, clang-UBSAN:
CC="clang -fsanitize=address,undefined -fno-sanitize=float-divide-by-zero -fno-sanitize=alignment -fno-omit-frame-pointer"
CXX="clang++ -fsanitize=address,undefined -fno-sanitize=float-divide-by-zero -fno-sanitize=alignment -fno-omit-frame-pointer -frtti"
CFLAGS="-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic"
FFLAGS="-g -O2 -mtune=native"
CXXFLAGS="-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic"
MAIN_LD="clang++ -fsanitize=undefined,address"

export ASAN_OPTIONS='detect_leaks=0:detect_odr_violation=0'
export UBSAN_OPTIONS='print_stacktrace=1'
export RGL_USE_NULL="true"
export R_DONT_USE_TK="true"
```

4. run

```
./configure \
    --prefix=/opt/R/${R_VERSION} \
    --enable-memory-profiling \
    --enable-R-shlib \
    --with-blas \
    --with-lapack
```

5. run `make`

Then we can check if it actually works by running R in `bin/R` and triggering errors using the package `sanitizers`.

```r
install.packages("sanitizers")
sanitizers::stackAddressSanitize(42)
sanitizers::heapAddressSanitize(10)
```

Then use R as usual and install your package as usual